# unit vector that lies in the xy plane and perpendicular to vector u

Tags: vectors

given a vector u <1,-2,1> find a unit vector perpendicular to u and lies in the xy-plane

all i know is that since it lies in the xy plane, the vector should be <(x),y,0> and that the dot product of this particular vector(v) and vector u must be 0
so vector u dot vector v would be x-2y=0 then x=2y
i assign a value to x which is 2 so that vector v would be <2,1,0> and ||v|| would be sqrt of 5
the unit vector that is perpendicular to vector u and is in the xy plane would then be <2/sqrt 5, 1/sqrt 5, 0>

is this correct at all???? any hints, tips, or suggestion would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct - spot on.

Comment: You could point that vector in the opposite vector, too (multiply by -1) to get the other perpendicular vector.

Comment: ohh. thanks @tomi